# How to save mschart to word from webform

Tags: asp.net, report, mschart

I have tried for 2 days saving a mschart to a word document. No matter what I do, I cant save the chart. I have a gridview, and I have saved that fine, but not the chart.

```
  Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.doc")
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word"
    Dim oStringWriter As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim oHtmlTextWriter As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter)

    ' Chart1.SaveImage("C:\temp\chart.jpg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg)

    ' GridView1.DataBind()

    GridView33.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter)
    Response.Output.Write(oStringWriter.ToString())
    Response.Output.Write(oStringWriter)


    'the chart part 
    Chart1.SaveImage(Server.MapPath("\WebCharts\Chart.Jpeg"))
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Bmp)
    Dim bm As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms)
    Dim strHTMLContent As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    strHTMLContent.Append(bm.ToString())


    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Comment: I wouldn't think it works like that: you have to use the office libraries in VS to create an actual MS Office document. While you're creating that document, you'll need to add your image saved from the chart... Then, stream the whole doc down to client.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the RenderType property of your chart to ImageTag.
Then save your page as a word document.